# Почему posts.DeletionDate не содержит ни одного значения на data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: обсуждение, data-explorer

Для интереса и тренировки в SQL пишу квери на data.SE

```sql
select top 1024 * from posts where DeletionDate is not NULL order by score desc;
```

Должно, по идее, выдавать 1024 удаленных вопроса/ответа с наибольшим score'ом. Но получаю пустую таблицу. Код вроде правильный. Так что спрашиваю на мете. Почему?

Comment: С такими вопросами лучше на основной сайт, но в данном случае не стоит. Что вы хотите с таким условием `DeletionDate <> NULL`? Это же грубейшая ошибка, даже для новичков.

Comment: @0xdb Так в sql я и есть новичок ;) А что не так? Я чет перепутал? Извините за тупизну ;)

Comment: `DeletionDate is not  NULL`

Comment: @0xdb Точно! Во я конечно... Ну вообщем-то так тоже ничего не показывает. Думаю дело не тока в этом.

Comment: Дате ссылку на data.se.

Comment: @0xdb https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1289045

Comment: DeletionDate всегда NULL, см. ответ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Таблица `Posts` содержит только сообщения, которые не удаляются.
Таблица `PostsWithDeleted` содержит *некоторую* информацию об удаленных сообщениях:
[Can some metadata about deleted posts be included in Data.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462/295232)

Comment: Please take a look on [this topic](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12934/176217).