# Правки по вставке несуществующих изображений: принимать или отклонять?

Tags: обсуждение, правки, предлагаемые-правки

Последние дни мне приходили на проверку правки ([пример1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/873393), [пример2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/873883)), в которых вместо ссылок вставлялись изображения по этим ссылкам - вообще-то, я поддерживаю такие правки, да и сам их иногда делаю, но проблема в том, что картинки по ссылке уже не существует, и в результате вставляется вот такая картинка:

[image]

Первую такую правку я отклонил, так как посчитал, что она не добавляет информации, но сообщество решило иначе:

[image]

Кто же всё-таки прав?

PS: Я знаю, что предложивший правку участник [**@Glorfindel**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/223536) является модератором в многих сообществах, но всё же...

Comment: Считаю, что нет разницы между битой картинкой и ссылкой на битую картинку. Смысла в такой правке не вижу.

Comment: Apologies, my script knows of hundreds of bad / placeholder images, but not this one yet. It detects those by comparing the MD5 hash of the file against a known blocklist, not by trying to read the content of the image. I have now added this image, so the script shouldn't make those edits anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Упомянутые правки (предложения о правках) сделаны программно, о чём можно почитать по [ссылке](https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83/9d954d34385d2ac2597bbe864466259f) из описания к самой [предложенной правке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/873883).

Как указано в описании, правки делаются от лица автора программы, но автоматически, т.е. самим автором правки не проверяются. Почему проверяющие принимают такие правки - это вопрос. Надеюсь, там нет другой автоматики, что один скрипт проверяет результаты работы другого :)

Обе правки я отклонил.
Всем упомянутым в предложенных правках участникам, я дал ссылку на текущий вопрос.

Comment: Мой косяк, не обратил внимания, что замена на плэйсхолдер. Ранее сталкивался с подобными правками, были замены на нормальные картинки.

Comment: Не заметил замену на плейсхолдер, буду внимательнее